# How to parse a string with GMT into datetime in c#

Tags: c#, date-parsing

I have this inputDateString: `15/03/2023 15:13:37 GMT` and I want to convert it to datetime.

I am doing this: `DateTime outputDate = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDateString, "MM/dd/yyyy:hhmmss \"GMT\"", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

I get this error: `c# String '10/05/2023 18:19:27 GMT' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

How can I convert this date string to a datetime?

Comment: While you probably still need to adjust your format, I'd recommend parsing to DateTimeOffset rather than DateTime.

Comment: What timezone is your current computer in? Will you always get input strings that end with "GMT"?

Comment: Yes, I will always get input strings that end with "GMT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your format date incorrect ,This code is correct,better but you must specify the timezone

```
DateTime outputDate = DateTime.ParseExact("15/03/2023 15:13:37 GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Is there a way to format the output while still keeping it a date? For example right now the output is in this format: `Feb 28 2023  6:29AM`, but I want it to be in this format: `2023-05-13 01:40:34`

Comment: If this is what you mean, when we convert it to a string, it should be in that format. You can use this code "outputDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")"

Comment: I am saving to a sql table date field.  I want the value I send to sql to be a date formatted as `2023-05-13 01:40:34`, not a string.

Comment: If you send a date to the database, it will be sent as a date and it will be known there and can use format

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("15/03/2023 15:13:37 GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Should do the trick to parse from string to DateTime. If you want to mess with the timezones I recommend you to read about the `DateTimeOffset` class.

Having a DateTime class allows you to parse it to string the way you need passing the format you want:

```
Console.WriteLine( date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```